# Get Remote unit name in subordinate charm

Tags: juju, python3

In my juju model I have a few applications running and I have a subordanite charm attached to one of those:

```
Unit                Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports            Message
mycharm/0*           active    idle   4        192.168.1.34   80/tcp           ready
wordpress/0*         unknown   idle   2        192.168.1.48   80/tcp
  trustysub/0*       active    idle            192.168.1.48                    ready
```

Now I want my `trustysub` subordinate charm to know the unit_name of the unit he is attached to (`wordpress/0`). So when I add the relation `juju add-relation wordpress trustysub`, I can write the unit name of `Wordpress` to a file or something.

```
@when('myrelation.available')
def write_unit_name():
    # code to get unitname
    f = open('myfile', 'w')
    f.write('unitname')
    f.close()
    status_set('active', 'ready')
```

my `metadata.yml` looks like this:

```
name: trustysub
summary: test charm
maintainer: Sebastien Pattyn <sebastien.pattyn@gmail.com>
description: |
  This subordinate charm writes the unitname from the charm it has a relationship with, to a file
tags: ['misc']
subordinate: true
requires:
  subrelation:
    interface: juju-info
    scope: container
series: ['trusty']
```

Any idea on what I should add in my code to get the unitname of Wordpress in my subordinate charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Charmhelpers.core.hookenv](https://pythonhosted.org/charmhelpers/api/charmhelpers.core.hookenv.html) package has some functions that can be used to get information about a a relation. Importing the package will give you the possibility to return the Remote unit by using the `remote_unit()` method. This will return the specific remote Unit for the current relation Hook.

You can use it like this.

```
from charmhelpers.core.hookenv import remote_unit

@when('myrelation.available')
def write_unit_name():
    f = open('myfile', 'w')
    f.write(remote_unit())
    f.close()
    status_set('active', 'ready')
```